# jQuery generic code

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I am using jQuery modal dialogs in my app to handle normal CRUD operations. In some cases I have even two stacked modal dialogs open.

I have then created two generic function in an external javascript file to handle respectively the showing and the submit of CRUD forms.

To show modal dialogs I call the following function

```
function _loadDialog(level, action, id, title, onCloseHandler) {
    var panel = panels[level];
    $(panel).dialog("option", "title", title);
    var url = action;
    if (id != "") url = url + "/" + id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        dataType: "html",
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function(response) {
            $(panel).html('').html(response).dialog('open');
        }
    });
    $(panel).unbind("dialogclose").bind("dialogclose", function(event, ui) {
        if (onCloseHandler != null) {
            onCloseHandler();
        }
    });
}
```

This function receive, among the others, a `level` parameter that instruct the function how to stack the dialog and where to place the rendered Partial markup returning back from the ajax call. This function works fine.

Inside the Partial View returned by the ajax call there are input and at the end the following code

```
<div style="text-align:right;">
    <input type="submit" id="btnSave" value="Salva" />
</div>
```

and, for the jQuery part, for example,

```
$("#contactForm").submit(function(event) {
    _submitForm(1, event, "#contactForm", "post", "html", '<%= Url.Content("~/Contact/Save") %>');
});
```

As you can see the submit function has the following signature

```
function _submitForm(level, event, formName, atype, adataType, aurl) {
}
```

and it handle

- the form submission to the correct controller action
- the user feedback (e.g. "action executed successfully")
- the dialog close operation

The level parameter is needed to address all the function, including closing the dialog, to the correct DIV panel used.

I would like to be able to show the same dialog sometimes as a dialog and sometimes as a sub dialog.
To be able to do this, I mean "logically speaking" as I am not so strong with javascript and jQuery, I need the following changes:

- Modify the `_loadDialog` function to save the `level` parameter inside the dialog markup itself
- Modify the `_submitForm` function and make it using the correct `level` parameter that has been previously saved from the `_loadDialog` function.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's the current relationship between these two functions? Is `_submitForm` called from the `onCloseHandler` you pass into `_loadDialog`?

Comment: @VoteyDisciple: No. `_submitForm` is called by a click event of a submit button inside the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused about what is where and when, but it seems that you want to associate a bit of information with a particular element.

To do this, you can use jQuery's `.data()` method. It will associate whatever data you want with a particular element.

Not sure how exactly it should be used in your situation, but here's a generic example:

```
$('#someSelector').data('level', 3);
```

Now the element with the ID `someSelector` will have the number `3` mapped to its `'level'` attribute in its associated data.

So to retrieve it, you would do this:

```
$('#someSelector').data('level'); // returns 3
```

When destroying an element that has data associated with it (this is just one example of such data), you should be sure to use `.remove()` or `.empty()` or one of the other methods that either automatically or manually removes the data.

Comment: Ok. Basically I am trying to use always the same function `loadDialog` and `submitForm` either from my views and from my partial from any level of stacked dialog. So I need to make sure that when calling `submitForm` from a partial or view it will closes the correct dialog.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like all you need is to pass on the `level` parameter you've already got to the `_submitForm` function when calling it.

```
function _loadDialog(level, action, id, title, onCloseHandler) {
    var form = $('<form ...></form>');
    // ... Generates the form markup

    form.submit(function() {
        _submitForm(level, ...);
    });
}
```

While I've obviously skipped over all the details I don't know of your implementation, the key is simply that whatever `level` gets passed into `_loadDialog` will later get passed into `_submitForm` when it's called.

In JavaScript, it doesn't matter that `_submitForm` isn't called at the same time you call `_loadDialog`. Through what's called a "closure" (something JavaScript programmers love to talk about), the `level` variable gets saved safely inside your anonymous callback function for `form.submit()` and will still be available with the same value when that function is eventually called.

Comment: Ok. I can really understand your suggestion and it seems very easy to implement. Anyway I am not sure this will work within my implementation because is not so simple as the form variable you are using. I am going to edit my question to add more details on the two functions to give you a better understanding of the details. It would great if you can have a look at it. Thank you!

Comment: It would be easier if during the dialog creation I could add a invisible section to the dialog markup that the code inside the partial can query. Inside this section I could place the level value