# Dynamically adding a div to another one using jQuery

Tags: jquery, dom-manipulation

Suppose I have the following DIV

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none" title=""></div>
```

I have an ajax call that append HTML markup to this div using

```
$("#myDiv").html('').html(response);
```

I would like to append hidden content to the main div before the response content so the result would be

```
<div id="myDiv" style="display:none" title="">
    //my hidden content
    //here there will be the response HTML markup    
</div>
```

How can I do it using jQuery code?

Comment: Just add another div after your hidden content and add to that?

Comment: do you want to have a permanent hidden content and replace each time his following siblings ?

Comment: With the code I am using I have one child node of `myDiv` being added. I want to add another child node of `myDiv` before the one that

Comment: @Riccardo Galli: Yes that one is an alternative that I can follow

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `.html()` overwrites anyway, there's really no need to do `.html('')`.

This will first set the hidden content, then it [will `.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) the response.

```
$("#myDiv").html('<span class="hidden">somehiddencontent</span>')
           .append(response);
```

CSS

```
span.hidden { display:none; }
```

You could also do it in one shot:

```
$("#myDiv").html('<span class="hidden">somehiddencontent</span>' + response);
```

If there's *any* chance that there will be jQuery managed data inside `#myDiv`, it would be safer to [use `.empty()`](http://api.jquery.com/empty/) before `.html()`.

```
$("#myDiv").empty()
           .html('<span class="hidden">somehiddencontent</span>' + response);
```

Comment: Good. I am going to try it. I am trying to do this just to solve the problem described here: `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172511/jquery-generic-code` can you have a look at it?

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#myDiv").html('').append(something).append(somethingElse);
```

or `prepend()` if you want to do it in the opposite order.